# iPhone does not respond to DHCP request/discover from our Linux-based system

Tags: network, bluetooth

We have the following problem:

An iPhone is acting as a Network Access Point under the PAN Bluetooth profile, but it does not respond to DHCP request/discover from our Linux-based system. The PAN connection can be established, but no IP address is assigned.

Steps to Reproduce:
- Activate Bluetooth on iPhone (5C iOS 10.3.2, but also seen in 6S iOS 11.x)
- Activate Bluetooth tethering on iPhone
- Pair our Linux-based system to iPhone via Bluetooth (PAN profile, NAP service)
- Execute dhclient in our Linux-based system.

Expected Results:
- The iPhone assigns an IP address via DHCP to our Linux-based system.

Actual Results:
- The iPhone does not respond to DHCP request/discover from our Linux-based system.

Is there any special handling/protocol in order to get an IP address and establish the PAN communication?

Comment: Does it work with non apple devices (i.e. Android?)  I don't think this is an Apple one, but rather something to do with Linux - in which case, this is the wrong site.

Comment: It does work with an Android device connecting to the iPhone PAN, however we were wondering why there's no response at all from DHCP (no Ethernet frames addressed to our Linux-based system from the iPhone's address)

Comment: How are you determining there's no response at all?  Are you seeing a DHCP request from the iPhone but the server doesn't respond?  What are you using to "see" these request/response packets?

Comment: We use a virtual network interface (TAP) in the Linux system, thus we can monitor the Ethernet frames coming in and out.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, no special handling is necessary for iPhones. Create a question at the Unix & Linux StackExchange, and remember to include vital information such as: Your Linux distribution, whether you're using the gnome-bluetooth/blueman GUI (or other GUI), netcfg or manual configuration, your bluez configuration files and arguments given to dhclient, output from bluetoothctl, ifconfig/ip and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all,

The problem was solved by setting the MAC address manually right after the TAP interface was created

Answer (score 0):

(This isn’t an answer, rather a path to build one.)

Check on `iPhone`, and `Linux`, that the only network interfaces up are:

- `iPhone`: phone network + Bluetooth (`Settings > Wi-Fi > Off`,…),
- `Linux`: Bluetooth (`ifconfig -a`).

Answer (score -1):

No, no special handling/protocol is needed. The iPhone in this respect is just like any other Bluetooth device offering a network aggregation point.

Your question should be directed to the Unix & Linux StackExchange instead.